# Why does CMake FILE(READ) ignore semicolons in my file?

Tags: cmake

I have a css file (which I want to parse and adapt for Qt, but that's not the problem). Let's say this one:

```
QLineEdit:hover:not(focus),
QWidget QPlainTextEdit:not(hover):not(focus) {
    border-color: #5575b0;
}
```

I made a CMake script to replace `not(...)` by `!...` : that part of the script works correctly.

The problem is that CMake removes the semicolons (`;`) at the end of lines. When I do:

```
file(READ ${INPUT_FILE_PATH} CONTENT)
message(${CONTENT})
```

The output is, unfortunately :

```
QLineEdit:hover:not(focus),
QWidget QPlainTextEdit:not(hover):not(focus) {
    border-color: #5575b0 // <-- missing comma here !
}
```

As anyone an idea why this happen ? And how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out what the problem is : CMake considers my input as a list, in which elements are separated by a comma (`;`).

To avoid that, we have to add quotes to the variable, like this `"${MY_VAR}"` :

```
message("${CONTENT}")
```

Comment: Just wanted to add two references and a quote: [0010107: file(READ removes semicolons](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=10107) and [0002770: semicolons are dropped when reading files with FILE(READ ...)](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=2770): "Yes, lists in CMake are just strings with semicolon delimiters."